# Ads integration on tableviewcell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, tableview

*Will my app get rejected in app store if include Ads in tableview cells?*
When  browse it seems a lot of threads which holds the point "Don't know exactly will it be accepted or rejected". But it seems CNN App has the same feature included.
Also I have tried a third party(`mo_pub`) to integrate ads in my app. The ads get displayed in tableview cell exactly what I expect,but need to confirm if the app will get reject if I use the same or is their any other options to implements this in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used but I read at several place that Apple allows other ad services such as **AdMob** and **adwhirl**.

Comment: Thanks,Can you please  provide urls, if any

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start and http://jmsliu.com/1207/add-google-admob-in-ios-apps.html

Comment: The above mentioned url shows how we can place the Ads in a UITableView Header and Footer,but can u please mention any urls that points to place Ads in nth position of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Apple should not reject the app as I think. But most of the app display banner ads either at the bottom or top.